# How to write an extbase Repository-Method for Update in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have written an update query in TYPO3, Now I need to change it to query-object repository method. How to change the code below?

```
public function updatePaymentDetails($uid, $txnID, $amt, $stats)
{
    $itemUID = $uid;
    $transID = $txnID;
    $amountPaid = $amt;
    $txStatus = $stats;
    $tableName = 'tx_paypalpayment_domain_model_transactions AS tpp';
    $whereCondition = 'tpp.uid=' . '"' . $itemUID . '"';
    $setValues = ['transactionid' => $transID, 'amount' => $amountPaid, 'txnstatus' => $txStatus];
    $result = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery($tableName, $whereCondition, $setValues);
    return $result;
}
```

I created this much in my own idea (don't know it is correct or not), What should be the remaining portion?

```
public function paymentUpdate($uid, $txnID, $amt, $stats) {
   $query = $this->createQuery();
   $query->matching(
      $query->logicalAnd(
         $query->equals("transactionid", $txnID),
         $query->equals("amount", $amt),
         $query->equals("txnstatus", $stats)
      )
   );

   /*---   Update Code   ---*/

   return $query->execute();
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TYPO3/Extbase way is to first fetch your transaction from the persistence layer then apply your changes to the domain object and then update it in your repository.

Something like below in your controller action:

```
$transaction = $this->transactionRepository->findByIdentifier($itemUid);
$transaction->setTransactionId($transID);
$transaction->setAmount($amountPaid);
$transaction->setStatus($txStatus);
$this->transactionRepository->update($transaction);
```

If you wants to do a direct update instead of first fetching the record then take a look at the `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder` (Only exists in newer versions of TYPO3 - 8.7 and above). In older versions of TYPO3 you could take a look at `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_*`.